# Reducing homogeneous second order differential equation to first order (Operator factorisation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

I need to reduce the homogeneous second-order differential equation

$\ y'' + by' + cy = 0$

to a first-order one using operator factorisation, where$\ b, c$ and$\ y$ are functions of t.

I began by rewriting it in operator form and completing the square, getting

$\ [(D + \dfrac{b}{2})^2 + (c - \dfrac{b^2}{4})]y = 0$.

I'm basically stumped from here. I could try applying$\ D^2$ to both sides to get zero on the right-hand side and then substitute, but then I run into more dead-ends that give me no hints to either proceed or point to a different approach (at least in my mind).

Can someone help out with suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean to factor is into first order operators whose composite acts on $y$? Or, do you mean to use reduction of order to replace the one second order ODE with a system of first order ODEs?

Comment: Also, if $b$ and $c$ are functions of $t$ I think your algebra fails.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to factor into first-order operators.

Comment: Well, I suppose you could find it by taking the solutions and working backwards. But, given nonconstant coefficients, the operators do not commute and to solve it we use substitution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write 
$$(D+\alpha)(D+\beta)y=0$$
This gives
$$D^{2}y+(\alpha+\beta)Dy+\alpha\beta{y}=0$$
Comparing with your equation, you get 
$$\alpha+\beta=b$$
and 
$$\alpha\beta=c$$
Then you let $g(x)=(D+\beta)y(x)$ and you are left with a first order system
$$g'+\alpha{g}=0, \ y'+\beta{y}=g$$
The first equation is solved by
$$g(x)=c_{1}e^{-\alpha{x}}$$
The second equation is solved by the integrating factor technique 
$$y(x)=c_{2}e^{-\beta{x}}+c_{1}\frac{e^{-\alpha{x}}}{\beta-\alpha}$$